# Where is the "start" command file?

Tags: python, windows

I want another python script that I run on the main python script to run in a separate window. I found out that if I use `start script.py` from cmd, the script runs in a separate window, not in current terminal. So, I want to run the same from a python script, but there is no path to start.exe in sys.path. So where is this file located so I can add it to sys.path so that I can run scripts this way? Or can I run scripts in a separate window in other better ways?

Comment: It's a built in command.  Use something like `cmd /c start script.py` to run from outside of `cmd`.

Comment: @AnonCoward, thanks, that works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `start` command is built in, to run it outside of `cmd`, including python scripts, we can use `cmd /c start script.py`. This works for me.